# How to get the routes available for the authenticated user

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, fosjsroutingbundle

I'm setting up FOSJsRoutingBundle on my app. When doing this I realized that the endpoint that returns all routes for the app, there was returning all routes for my internal app. I was digging in the source code, and they didn't apply any filters to the routes returned based on user roles. This is very insecure way of doing things, because for me I can't reveal all the internal routing configuration for my app, because it will lead a security breach, if someone used for example DevTools from chrome check for access to every route in my internal app. The question is, there is a way of accomplishing that, return only the routes accessible for the current user?

Comment: maybe in router.yaml option: expose:false??? did you try it

Comment: http://prntscr.com/maku2e you people need to read the documentation -> link https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Comment: You actually did't understand a word. I read documentation. I don't want to avoid route exposition, I just want to avoid exposure based on roles. My client app uses the router provided, if I remove routes based on exposure, the client app will never generate the correct route even if the user have access to that one.

Comment: well, `fosjsrouting` creates a static file, which means you need to generate as much files as roles you have, and those files should be included dynamically depending on current user role. `fosjsrouting` does not support role based strategy and you should extend it yourself. though, I don't know why do you need this, if a user is not allowed to review some endpoint, then what would happen if he will discover it from devtools? he will get 403 response as not authenticated

Comment: It will be used to avoid human errors. If someone forgets to setup Security annotation in a particular route. Anyone knowing the endpoints, can access to that feature. Thanks!

Comment: This is why you need automated e2e tests, like `Behat`. Cover all your endpoints with tests, make sure `Security` annotation is not missed anywhere. User should access only features according to his role, but not a feature he discovered from `fosjsrouting` file. Moreover, if user knows a part of your endpoints, then it is not that hard to guess another ones, for example if you have `api/users` end point, probably you also have `api/clients` or whatever, depending on your app structure:)

Comment: It can be accomplished by [creating a separate environment](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html) for your "internal" app. So instead of `bin/console --env=prod` you would have `bin/console --env=internal` This will provide you with a separate set of declarations for everything Symfony provides, Then you would need to update your web server configs to set the environment. Use a different path for your env JS file `bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --env=internal --target=/public/js/internal_routes.js` and update your templates.

Comment: @LuninRoman a [Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html) can also be used to enforce the `@Security` annotation when a route is set to be exposed. Since Behat and PHPUnit are for all intents and purposes optionally run. The Compiler Pass could throw an exception, preventing Symfony from generating the container.

Comment: This is not about enviorenments

Comment: @LuninRoman it's just one approach by using separation of concerns for the routes.  The concern is the generation of the `js_routing` file for each role, to avoid exposing all routes in the app to any role. Segregating the exposed routes based on environment, by making `^/secured` a separate environment, only the routes available to that environment would be generated, accomplishing the desired end-result.

Comment: For reference, there is a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/65) addressing this issue specifically.

Comment: A [pull request](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/346) was merged in `v2.3.0` that now allows you to specify the exposed routes by domain.`options={expose:"my_domain"}` Then in your template you can use `path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData", "domain": "my_domain"})`